# Why isn’t my CSS accordion working? Beginner here

Tags: css, accordion

I’m very new to CSS and therefore apologise if I’m missing something incredibly obvious here.

I found some code for a clean CSS accordion which I wanted to use into my site.

I got it to display but when I click, nothing happens. It doesn’t open and I’m guessing there’s either something fundamental missing or I got a bit of code wrong.

Could anybody please help? I’d amended to add in an icon representing open and close too which I wanted on the left with the text next to it.

[I’ve added everything to this CodePen.](https://codepen.io/MixAway/pen/qBrgveb)

```css
.gohere-accordion {
    /* Border */
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.gohere-accordion__item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.gohere-accordion__header {
    /* Center the content horizontally */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;

    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px;
}

.gohere-accordion__toggle {
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.gohere-accordion__title {
    /* Take remaining width */
    flex: 1;
}

.gohere-accordion__content {
    /* For not selected item */
    display: none;

    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 16px;
}

.gohere-accordion__content--selected {
    /* For selected item */
    display: block;
}

.gohere-control-icon {
  fill: #154ae5;
  transition: .3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gohere-control-icon-close {
  display: none;
}

details[open] .gohere-control-icon-close {
  display: initial;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

details[open] .gohere-control-icon-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Container -->
<div class="gohere-accordion"><!-- Each accordion item -->
    <div class="gohere-accordion__item"><!-- Heading -->
        <div class="gohere-accordion__header"><!-- The toggle icon -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__toggle">
                <svg class="gohere-control-icon gohere-control-icon-expand" height="24" role="presentation" width="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#expand-more" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                </svg> 
                <svg class="gohere-control-icon control-icon-close" height="24" role="presentation" width="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#close" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- The title -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__title">Question One</div>
         </div>
            <!-- The content -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__content">Answer One</div>
      </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure there was no accompanying JS code for this accordion?

Comment: Yup, the code is incomplete. No javascript and no CSS to respond to `hover`, `focus` or other states of elements. @MixAway, please research your source and see what is missing. Also, as for the CodePen example, you can do the same right here just by adding a snippet, as an alternative to posting code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript for a simple toggle function to check what value `display` has on your desired content and then set it accordingly.

```js
let
  header = document.querySelector( '.gohere-accordion__header' ),
  content = document.querySelector( '.gohere-accordion__content' );

function accordionToggle() {
  if( content.style.display != 'block' ) {
    content.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

header.addEventListener( 'click', accordionToggle );
```

```css
.gohere-accordion {
    /* Border */
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.gohere-accordion__item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.gohere-accordion__header {
    /* Center the content horizontally */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;

    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px;
}

.gohere-accordion__toggle {
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.gohere-accordion__title {
    /* Take remaining width */
    flex: 1;
}

.gohere-accordion__content {
    /* For not selected item */
    display: none;

    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 16px;
}

.gohere-accordion__content--selected {
    /* For selected item */
    display: block;
}

.gohere-control-icon {
  fill: #154ae5;
  transition: .3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gohere-control-icon-close {
  display: none;
}

details[open] .gohere-control-icon-close {
  display: initial;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

details[open] .gohere-control-icon-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Container -->
<div class="gohere-accordion"><!-- Each accordion item -->
    <div class="gohere-accordion__item"><!-- Heading -->
        <div class="gohere-accordion__header"><!-- The toggle icon -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__toggle">
                <svg class="gohere-control-icon gohere-control-icon-expand" height="24" role="presentation" width="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#expand-more" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                </svg> 
                <svg class="gohere-control-icon control-icon-close" height="24" role="presentation" width="24">
                    <use xlink:href="#close" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- The title -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__title">Question One</div>
         </div>
            <!-- The content -->
            <div class="gohere-accordion__content">Answer One</div>
      </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. So the JS snippet you posted should make this work? I have to apologise as I’m completely new to this!

Comment: @MixAway Click the button in the snippet and see if it works how you expect for yourself. When you click the header it shows the content underneath - I’m assuming this is what you wanted. And yes all I added was this JavaScript above. If this answers your question please accept this answer.